# Jenkins GitSCM checkout poll option

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I cannot understand the option poll in the GitSCM plugin. I know poll is used to quickly check if there are any changes in the repository which requires a build trigger. However, I do not understand what poll option does when inside pipeline we need to clone a repo into the build workspace:

```
checkout 
    changelog: true, 
    poll: false, 
    scm: [
        $class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"]], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false
    ]
```

I have a job configured to scan every 5 minutes for changes in repository. I am using Multibranch scripted pipeline with Global Shared Library defined. Thank you for explanation.